# How to convolve a 3 dimensional array (in this case a filter bank) with a 2 dimensional image (monochrome) in Python?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy, computer-vision

I have a function definition that takes in an image that is monochromatic and 2 dimensional, and a filter bank that is a 3 dimensional array (48 2D filters). I need to convolve the two to find the feature vector at each pixel location. How do I do that?

I have tried `scipy.ndimage.convolve()` but get the error "filter weights array has incorrect shape."

Comment: What do you expect the output to be? What is the 3D filter kernel? Is it meant for a 3D image or for a color image?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Technically the 3 dimensional  filter is a filter bank containing 48 filters. It is meant for a color image. My goal is to apply the filter using convolution to the monochrome image(2 dimensional) and achieve the feature vector at each pixel location

Comment: Ah! That is useful information that should be [edit]ed into your question. The two answers below made wrong assumptions about what you're after.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Sorry I was trying to keep the question as simple as possible. I will edit that in. Any idea on how to go about it though?

Comment: I would simply loop over the 48 filters in the filter bank, apply the convolution operation for each of them separately to the image, and collect the results in a 3D matrix.

Comment: @CrisLuengo So if my filter bank named filt is size (49,49,48) could I try something like: 'for i in range(filt.shape[0]): result = scipy.ndimage.convolution(img,filt(i)) '

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216977/discussion-between-lceans-and-cris-luengo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make things simple, simply loop over the temporal dimension of your filter bank, then apply convolution to the image and each filter within the filter bank.  After, stack the results into a 3D matrix.  This is actually what I would do for readability.

Suppose your image is stored in `img` and your filters are stored in `filters`.  `img` is of size `M x N` and your filters are of size `R x C x D` with `D` being the total number of filters you have.

As you've eluded to using [`scipy.ndimage.convolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.convolve.html), we can just use that.  However, it's possible to use [`cv2.filter2D`](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/d86/group__imgproc__filter.html#ga27c049795ce870216ddfb366086b5a04) too.  I'll show you how to use both.

## Method #1 - Using `scipy.ndimage.convolve`

```py
import scipy.ndimage
import numpy as np

outputs = []
D = filters.shape[2]
for i in range(D):
    filt = filters[...,i]
    out = scipy.ndimage.convolve(img, filt)
    outputs.append(out)

outputs = np.dstack(outputs)
```

The above is straight forward.  Create an empty list to store our convolution results, then extract the total number of filters we have.  After, we loop over each filter, convolve the image with said filter and append it to the list.  We then use [`numpy.dstack`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html) to stack all of the 2D responses together to a 3D matrix.

## Method #2 - Using `cv2.filter2D`

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

outputs = []
D = filters.shape[2]
for i in range(D):
    filt = filters[...,i]
    filt = filt[::-1, ::-1]
    out = cv2.filter2D(img, -1, filt)
    outputs.append(out)

outputs = np.dstack(outputs)
```

This is exactly the same as Method #1 with the exception of calling `cv2.filter2D` instead.  Also take note that I had to rotate the kernel by 180 degrees as `cv2.filter2D` performs **correlation** and not convolution.  To perform convolution with `cv2.filter2D`, you need to rotate the kernel first prior to running the method.  Take note that the second parameter to `cv2.filter2D` is the output data type of the result.  We set this to `-1` to say that it will be whatever the input data type is.

---

## Note on indexing

If you want to avoid indexing into your filter bank all together and let the `for` loop do that for you, you can shift the channels around so that the number of filters is the first channel.  You can then construct the resulting 3D output matrix by list comprehension:

```py
filters = filters.transpose((2, 0, 1))
outputs = np.dstack([scipy.ndimage.convolve(img, filt) for filt in filters])
```

Comment: What do you mean by copy the image three times?

Comment: `[img] * 3` takes the image and duplicates it three times.  Using `numpy.dstack` will stack these images to create a 3D / 3 channel image for you.  If this is confusing, the code is there for you to try it out.

Comment: Sorry I edited the question to be more specific. The filter I am using is actually a filter bank of 48 filters size of (49,49,48) and I want to find the output to be the feature vector at each pixel location

Comment: @lceans I've modified my answer.  The simplest way is to convolve each filter with the image separately in a loop and stack them all together.  In fact, this is what is done with most deep learning packages for the forward-pass of a conv 2D layer.

Comment: This is nice and simple, collecting the output in a list and then concatenating. I was thinking of copying the results into a 3D array directly, but that requires a bit more thinking. One note: `filter2D` is not the same as `convolve`, you would need to mirror the kernel to make them equivalent.

Comment: @CrisLuengo oh yes I forgot it does correlation.  If the filters are symmetric then we can leave this alone, but I will additionally rotate the kernel by 180 degrees prior to the filtering.

Comment: Yeah, it's probably unimportant, just something to be aware of in case of orientation-sensitive filters.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Also what you can do is permute the dimensions so that the channels appear first, then you can build the output response matrix as a list comprehension - probably faster.

Comment: I saw that addition. I've got a lot of Python to learn! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You can make the monochrome image a 3D array by either padding zeros or replicating the image itself. The number of such paddings would depend on the depth of convolution kernel. For example, let d be the depth of the convolution kernel and I is your image, then

```
I_pad = np.empty((I.shape[0], I.shape[1], 0))

# Do this for copying the image across channels
I_pad = [np.concatenate((I_pad, I), axis=-1) for _ in range(d)]

# Do this for zero padding
I_pad = [np.concatenate((I_pad, np.zeros(size(I))), axis=-1) for _ in range(d)]
```

Then carry out the convolution. Hope it helps

Comment: What is size that isn't recognized as anything?

Comment: `size(I)` is probably from MATLAB and this doesn't exist in NumPy. I suspect this person may want to use `np.zeros_like(I)`.... or to keep with this person's style: `np.zeros(I.shape)`.